# How can I make chef restart a service with additional parameters passed in?

Tags: sphinx, chef-infra

I have a template for a Rails site for Sphinx configuration.  There can be multiple different Sphinx services on the same machine running on different ports, one per app.  Therefore, I I only want to restart Sphinx for each site if their corresponding configuration template changes. I've created an /etc/init.d/sphinx script that restarts just one sphinx based on a parameter similar to:

```
/etc/init.d/sphinx restart /etc/sphinx/site1.conf
```

Where site1.conf is defined by a Chef template.  I'd really love to use the notifies functionality for Chef Templates to pass in the correct site1.conf parameter if the template changes.  Is this possible?

Alternatively, I suppose I could just register a different service for each site similar to:

```
/etc/init.d/sphinx_site1
```

However, I'd prefer to pass in the parameters to the script instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When defining a `service` resource, you can customize the start, stop, and restart commands that will be run. You can define a `service` resource for each site that you have using these customized commands and set up their corresponding notifications.

For example:

```
service "sphinx_site1" do
  supports :restart => true
  restart_command "/etc/init.d/sphinx restart /etc/sphinx/site1.conf"
  action :nothing
end

template "/etc/sphinx/site1.conf" do
  notifies :restart, "service[sphix_site1]"
end
```